# Wordpress - добавление нового поста

Tags: wordpress, post

При добавлении нового поста пропала возможно добавить миниатюру и категорию. Подскажите что не так или что изменить?

[image: Add new post]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справа вверху - настройки экрана.
Либо же тема без поддержки миниатюр.

Answer (score 1):

+SeVlad, да там сверху справа где Screen options - разверните и посмотрите, стоят ли там галки напротив нужных абзацев. Или вы установили тему оформления, которая не поддерживает такие возможности. Либо абзацы с категорией и миниатюрами свернуты и переехали под окно набора текста.